# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, archlinux, pacman-package-manager

I installed `tensorflow` on my arch linux computer via `pacman`. I tried to run the official [example code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py) for the mnist problem, but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnist_example.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/input_data.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist import read_data_sets
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import keras
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/keras/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.keras.api.keras import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/keras/api/keras/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.keras.api.keras import activations
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/keras/api/keras/activations/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras.activations import elu
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/keras/python/keras/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras import activations
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/keras/python/keras/activations.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras.engine import Layer
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/keras/python/keras/engine/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras.engine.training import Model
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/keras/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras import callbacks as cbks
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/keras/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard'
```

I couldn't locate a `tensorboard` folder and thus not the requested `projector` module in the `tensorflow/contrib/` folder. Do you know how I could solve that problem?

Comment: Then you need to install [it](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/tensorboard/)

Comment: @Drop I installed the package you linked, but it does not install the modules I need.

Comment: Which modules do you need then?

Answer (score 0):

As a dirty hack, you can download the corresponding Pip archive and copy the `contrib/tensorboard` directory in the archive to `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tensorboard`.